# Django multiple reshresh from view

Tags: django, django-views

I have some values in Django and I refresh them every 5 seconds on the page. I am using the ajax code below for this. But I have about 5 such values. I wonder what's the best way to do this?

view:

```
def ajax_system(request):
    system=get_system()
    return JsonResponse(system, safe=False)
```

template:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
 function() {
 setInterval(function(){
   $('#ajaxsystem').load('/ajaxsystem');
}, 5000)
});
</script>
```

Comment: do you want to use package or just wanna try other method

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just wonder which is the best way.